# I2C communication between MPU6050 and MSP430FR2433

Tags: i2c, msp430

I'm trying to communicate in I<sup>2</sup>C between a MSP430FR2433 and an [MPU6050](https://store.invensense.com/datasheets/invensense/MPU-6050_DataSheet_V3%204.pdf). I can send the start bit then the slave address (0x68) followed by the write bit (0) but the slave send me a NACK. I'm using the [GY-521 board](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse466/14au/labs/l4/MPU6050-V1-SCH-1024x599.jpg) and there are two pull-ups of 4k7. The clock is at 100 kHz which is under the maximum. I could once make the communication but since I always get a NACK

[image: I2C communication red clock blue data]

Comment: Schematic? Are you sure that your MPU is powered correctly and pin AD0 is LOW?

Comment: @mic The GY-521 board has a pulldown on AD0.

Comment: On the I²C bus, the high voltage level is the idle state. A NACK means that the slave device did not react *at all*. Maybe it isn't connected properly to the MSP or to the power supply.

Comment: @CL. Yes, just found the GY-521 schematic :-) Anyway, the pulldown may be broken ;-) But I agree it's more likely that there's a connection issue.

Comment: personally, I don't see the need for R6, I'd just put AD0 straight to GND

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the often confused issue of the slave address being considered a 7-bit quantity versus an 8-bit quantity?

When a slave address is considered an 8-bit quantity the least significant bit (LSB) of the address is the R/W bit so the slave device looks like it responds to two addresses, one for read and the other for write.

When specified as a 7-bit quantity the slave address is encoded as a value independent from the R/W bit.

Your waveform picture shows the 0x68 address encoded as 7-bits. But it could be that the device data sheet may have specified as an 8-bit in which case you may need to send out that first byte of the I2C protocol as a value of 0x68 instead of the 0xD0 value you have used now.

Comment: The MPU-6050 datasheet shows that the I²C address is 1101000.

Comment: @CL. - So seven bits then. Good to know. Likely a connection issue then.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, after having checked your suggestion, I finially change the sensor and it works.